# Elantech Touchpad Not Working ( Laggy, Stuttering )

Tags: drivers, touchpad, 19.10, synaptics, libinput

I recently bought a notebook. The touchpad works on Windows 10; but it doesnt on ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10. Didn't try it on other versions. It also doesn't work in live boots.

By "Doesn't work", I mean if I install synaptics driver, i can click right and left, but cursor moves laggy, as if connection gets lost randomly.

I listed some information below; but I don't even know what some of them mean, but you might.

### Info:

- Hp Pavilion Gaming 15 EC0006NT
- Amd Ryzen 5 3550H
- GTX 1650
- Ubuntu 19.10

### What I've tried:

Installed these drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mouse
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp"
```

I also tried to remove and reinstall the kernel, but messed it up a bit probably.

```
dogus@dogus:~$ dkms status
nvidia, 435.21, 5.3.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 435.21, 5.3.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed

dogus@dogus:~$ uname -rs
Linux 5.3.0-42-generic
```

### xinput list

```
dogus@dogus:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0718:01 04F3:30FD Touchpad            id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 System Control   id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru           id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

### lsmod

```
dogus@dogus:~$ lsmod | grep psmouse
psmouse               155648  0
```

### dmesg

```
dogus@dogus:~$ dmesg | grep pnp
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-42-generic root=UUID=d13d8fe8-8395-4fc6-b913-835a2f1c4ed4 ro quiet splash i8042.nopnp vt.handoff=7
[    0.030001] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-42-generic root=UUID=d13d8fe8-8395-4fc6-b913-835a2f1c4ed4 ro quiet splash i8042.nopnp vt.handoff=7
[    1.158534] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    1.158828] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    1.158855] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs HPQ8001 PNP0303 (active)
[    1.158873] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0f13 (active)
[    1.159855] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 5 devices


dogus@dogus:~$ dmesg | grep i8042
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-42-generic root=UUID=d13d8fe8-8395-4fc6-b913-835a2f1c4ed4 ro quiet splash i8042.nopnp vt.handoff=7
[    0.030001] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-42-generic root=UUID=d13d8fe8-8395-4fc6-b913-835a2f1c4ed4 ro quiet splash i8042.nopnp vt.handoff=7
[    1.349884] i8042: PNP detection disabled
[    1.364109] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.364112] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    1.444250] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
[    2.367540] input: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
```

### journalctl

Some of the output is in the pastebin page.I saw some errors in there. I can show all of the output if wished.

```
journalctl | grep -Ei 'i8042|pnp|elantech|touchpad'
```

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5zFNZhB5Dr/

### hwinfo

```
dogus@dogus:~$ hwinfo --mouse
39: USB 00.2: 10503 USB Mouse                                   
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: yqzE.4dlRdoZn0Z8
  Parent ID: k4bc.buxry1DL_88
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.2
  SysFS BusID: 1-3:1.2
  Hardware Class: mouse
  Model: "Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x045e "Microsoft Corp."
  Device: usb 0x07fd "Nano Transceiver 1.1"
  Revision: "3.15"
  Compatible to: int 0x0210 0x0025
  Driver: "usbhid"
  Driver Modules: "usbhid"
  Device File: /dev/input/mice (/dev/input/mouse2)
  Device Files: /dev/input/mice, /dev/input/mouse2, /dev/input/event11, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Microsoft_Microsoft_Nano_Transceiver_1.1-if02-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:05:00.3-usb-0:3:1.2-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Microsoft_Microsoft_Nano_Transceiver_1.1-if02-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:05:00.3-usb-0:3:1.2-mouse
  Device Number: char 13:63 (char 13:34)
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v045Ep07FDd0315dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02in02"
  Driver Info #0:
    Buttons: 5
    Wheels: 2
    XFree86 Protocol: explorerps/2
    GPM Protocol: exps2
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #43 (Hub)

49: PS/2 00.0: 10500 PS/2 Mouse
  [Created at input.249]
  Unique ID: AH6Q.9uGL5DibWf5
  Hardware Class: mouse
  Model: "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
  Vendor: 0x0002 
  Device: 0x000e "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
  Compatible to: int 0x0210 0x0001
  Device File: /dev/input/mice (/dev/input/mouse3)
  Device Files: /dev/input/mice, /dev/input/mouse3, /dev/input/event12, /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-1-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-1-mouse
  Device Number: char 13:63 (char 13:35)
  Driver Info #0:
    Buttons: 1
    Wheels: 0
    XFree86 Protocol: explorerps/2
    GPM Protocol: exps2
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

51: PS/2 00.0: 10500 PS/2 Mouse
  [Created at input.249]
  Unique ID: AH6Q.TnUycsDbFOF
  Hardware Class: mouse
  Model: "ELAN0718:01 04F3:30FD Touchpad"
  Vendor: 0x04f3 
  Device: 0x30fd "ELAN0718:01 04F3:30FD Touchpad"
  Compatible to: int 0x0210 0x0001
  Device File: /dev/input/mice (/dev/input/mouse0)
  Device Files: /dev/input/mice, /dev/input/mouse0, /dev/input/event15, /dev/input/by-path/platform-AMDI0010:01-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/platform-AMDI0010:01-mouse
  Device Number: char 13:63 (char 13:32)
  Driver Info #0:
    Buttons: 1
    Wheels: 0
    XFree86 Protocol: explorerps/2
    GPM Protocol: exps2
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

### glxinfo

```
dogus@dogus:~$ glxinfo | grep vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
```

### Optional Questions

Using Ubuntu is very important in my job domain.

- Is HP notebooks bad with linux distributions?
- Would this issue be solved in the future (e.g. in Ubuntu 20)?
- Does Elantech touchpads suck?

Thanks, I appreciate the help.

### UPDATE

Via live session, touchpad doesn't work at all at this point.
I installed libinput and the output at below:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo libinput list-devices
Device:           ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event5
Group:            9
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             114x58mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   none
Rotation:         n/a
```

### In Fedora 32 Beta Live USB Session

I wasn't clicking anything during the events below logged. I was just sliding one finger over the touchpad. And it was getting "laggy" right when the logs show "button state: ...".

I disabled every feature of touchpad: Touch to click, natural scrolling, two-finger scrolling, edge scrolling.

```
event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.724s  -11.67/ -4.01 (-32.00/-11.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.731s  -9.32/ -3.58 (-26.00/-10.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.738s  -6.12/ -1.36 (-18.00/ -4.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.745s  -7.47/ -1.36 (-22.00/ -4.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.751s  -7.81/ -1.02 (-23.00/ -3.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.758s  -5.78/ -1.36 (-17.00/ -4.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.764s  -8.15/ -0.68 (-24.00/ -2.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.771s  -8.83/  0.00 (-26.00/ +0.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.779s  -7.13/  0.34 (-21.00/ +1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.786s  -5.78/ -0.34 (-17.00/ -1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.792s  -7.13/  0.68 (-21.00/ +2.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.799s  -8.15/  0.34 (-24.00/ +1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.806s  -6.79/  0.00 (-20.00/ +0.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.812s  -7.81/  1.02 (-23.00/ +3.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.820s  -8.49/  0.68 (-25.00/ +2.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.827s  -7.13/  1.36 (-21.00/ +4.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.833s  -6.79/  0.68 (-20.00/ +2.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.840s  -7.13/  1.02 (-21.00/ +3.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.847s  -5.44/  0.34 (-16.00/ +1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.853s  -6.79/  1.36 (-20.00/ +4.00)
event12 - button state: touch 0 from BUTTON_STATE_AREA    event BUTTON_EVENT_UP          to BUTTON_STATE_NONE   
event12 - button state: touch 0 from BUTTON_STATE_NONE    event BUTTON_EVENT_IN_AREA     to BUTTON_STATE_AREA   
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.979s  -0.66/  0.66 ( -2.00/ +2.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.986s   0.00/  0.28 ( +0.00/ +1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +15.993s   0.32/  0.32 ( +1.00/ +1.00)
event12 - button state: touch 0 from BUTTON_STATE_AREA    event BUTTON_EVENT_UP          to BUTTON_STATE_NONE   
event12 - button state: touch 0 from BUTTON_STATE_NONE    event BUTTON_EVENT_IN_AREA     to BUTTON_STATE_AREA   
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.118s  12.91/  0.34 (+38.00/ +1.00)
event12 - button state: touch 0 from BUTTON_STATE_AREA    event BUTTON_EVENT_UP          to BUTTON_STATE_NONE   
event12 - button state: touch 0 from BUTTON_STATE_NONE    event BUTTON_EVENT_IN_AREA     to BUTTON_STATE_AREA   
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.237s   9.85/  0.00 (+29.00/ +0.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.244s  11.36/  0.00 (+33.00/ +0.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.251s   9.90/  0.35 (+28.00/ +1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.258s  14.68/  0.38 (+39.00/ +1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.265s  18.77/  0.44 (+43.00/ +1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.271s  12.95/  0.00 (+32.00/ +0.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.278s  12.28/  0.00 (+33.00/ +0.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.285s  10.35/  0.00 (+29.00/ +0.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.292s  10.67/  0.00 (+31.00/ +0.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.299s   8.61/  0.34 (+25.00/ +1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.306s  11.70/  0.71 (+33.00/ +2.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.312s  12.87/  0.76 (+34.00/ +2.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.319s   8.87/  0.71 (+25.00/ +2.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.326s   9.51/  0.00 (+28.00/ +0.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.333s   9.90/  0.68 (+29.00/ +2.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.340s  13.83/  0.37 (+37.00/ +1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.346s  13.00/  0.79 (+33.00/ +2.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.353s   9.64/  0.36 (+27.00/ +1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.360s   9.91/  0.34 (+29.00/ +1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.367s  10.09/  0.35 (+29.00/ +1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.374s   8.18/  0.34 (+24.00/ +1.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.381s  11.92/  1.40 (+34.00/ +4.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.388s  10.87/  0.00 (+30.00/ +0.00)
 event12  POINTER_MOTION   +16.395s   9.60/  0.34 (+28.00/ +1.00)
```

Comment: First of all, please don't try using synatpics drivers, they're long deprecated, and in maintainance mode at best. Please try checking on clean Ubuntu *(e.g by using live boot)* the following: 1. Make sure `libinput list-devices` lists your touchpad, 2. See if after executing `evemu-record` and trying to use touchpad *(e.g. touching it, clicking it)* triggers events in the output, 3. Repeat the previous check, but this time with `libinput debug-events --verbose` command instead. You may need to install some packages for these commands to be available. Please tell the results back.

Comment: For a long shot https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics

Comment: And please clarify the following: when you have libinput instead of synaptics *(which is by default in the system)*, does the touchpad not work at all, or is it "laggy and stuttering"? I'm asking because it's not quite clear from the question: as I'm reading it, it looks as if touchpad doesn't even respond with libinput, and is "laggy and stuttering" with synaptics. In case it behaves similarly both with libinput and synaptics, you can disregard my first comment here, I wrote it thinking that by default your touchpad doesn't even respond.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. The touchpad doesn't work at all. But if i install synaptics it works but "laggy" like as if using a broken mouse.
I will try evemu and inform you in short time.

Comment: I did the "sudo evemu-event <event number>" and touchpad triggers no events at all.
"libinput debug-events --verbose"
Touch pad didn't trigger any events.

Comment: You mean synaptics is already set when i boot up from live usb? touchpad doesn't work at all when I boot up live

Comment: I mean, you don't need synaptics. Ubuntu has libinput instead, and yes, it is already set when you boot from live usb. Okay, so, this is odd. You not seeing events in `evemu-event` means that synaptics driver shouldn't behave any different from libinput. Do you think touchpad with synaptics may have started responding *(even though it was laggy)* after you updated the kernel? Btw, I think quickest way to get out of hand possible problems with outdated sw may be if you try live USB by [Fedora 32 Beta](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/) and report back if it behaves any different.

Comment: I added my experience in Fedora in "Update" section. The kernel was "Linux 5.6.0-0.rc5.git0.2.fc32.x86_64". I feel like when logs have "BUTTON_STATE..." in it, the pointer gets laggy, Sometimes pointer just stops. "Feels like" computationally overwhelmed for brief periods, like miliseconds.

Comment: Thanks! Okay, so apparently the problem is: during sliding the finger over the touchpad libinput is getting spurious button events. This may be a bug in hw, kernel driver, libinput itself… Hard to tell right now. If you want to move forward with resolving this problem, best way [is to report a bug](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/reporting-bugs.html#reporting-bugs-touchpad). As a prerequisite, make sure you have latest libinput *(it is on fedora live usb, but not Ubuntu though)*, and that if you report it from ubuntu, you see libinput events too *(probably, upgrade kernel)*

Comment: Hello, the touchpad works! I changed the kernel to Linux 5.3.0-42-generic and it worked.
libinput version is 1.10.4. Right click button doesn't work though. But I am optimistic!

Comment: I own a HP Pavilion Gaming 15-ec0155ng (same touchpad), which I seem to have the same problem with. Everytime I interact with the UEFI firmware while boot, e.g. choosing a boot device (F9), the touchpad is working fine afterwards. So I set up a power-on password.

Comment: It sucks man, I still have to choose the Secure Boot option (F11) for the touchpad to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had two kernels installed apparently. 5.3.0-43 was the default one.

From advanced boot options I choosed the second kernel 5.3.0-42. The touchpad is working fine for the first time except for the right click doesn't work.

The libinput version is 1.10.4

Issue:
When I change GRUB_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub, the touchpad doesn't work afterwards.

GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-4d721fd2-5ba1-456b-a38e-41b803df3e83>gnulinux-5.3.0-42-generic-advanced-4d721fd2-5ba1-456b-a38e-41b803df3e83"

GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2" 
that doesn't work either.

**Why it works when I select a kernel manually from advanced options and why It doesn't work when it is manually configured via grub file?**

I was having an error during boot, after I changed the default kernel in grub file. Successfully booted but the touchpad wouldn't work.
The error was "Error unknown command hwmatch"
I did

```
sudo apt-get install -y grub-efi-amd64
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-efi-amd64
```

and haven't seen hwmatch error since. But I think the problem is related to that issue.

### UPDATE

I did a reboot, and the touchpad doesn't work again. The kernel is 5.3.0-42. There is an error from libinput in the logs, could it be the reason?

```
    dogus@dogus:~$ journalctl | grep libinput
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) libinput: Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control: needs a virtual subdevice
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 System Control'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) ELAN0718:01 04F3:30FD Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ELAN0718:01 04F3:30FD Touchpad'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) HP Wireless hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HP Wireless hotkeys'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) HP WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HP WMI hotkeys'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control'
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
Mar 26 22:21:11 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1997]: (II) libinput: Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control: is a virtual subdevice
Mar 27 11:47:24 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1510]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce: offset negative (-2905ms)
Mar 27 11:47:24 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1510]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce: offset negative (-2627ms)
Mar 27 11:47:24 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1510]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce short: offset negative (-2640ms)
Mar 27 11:47:24 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1510]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-857ms)
Mar 27 11:50:46 dogus sudo[3436]:    dogus : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/dogus ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt install libinput-tools
Mar 27 11:51:13 dogus sudo[4197]:    dogus : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/dogus ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/libinput debug-events --verbose
Mar 27 12:29:41 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1510]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-1887ms)
Mar 27 12:29:41 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1510]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-1408ms)
Mar 27 12:29:41 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1510]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-1218ms)
Mar 27 12:29:41 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1510]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-1067ms)
Mar 27 13:48:28 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1510]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-1134ms)
Mar 27 14:26:48 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1510]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce short: offset negative (-8ms)
Mar 27 20:56:21 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1510]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-1123ms)
Mar 27 20:56:21 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1510]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-748ms)
Mar 27 20:56:21 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1510]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-225ms)
Mar 27 21:13:05 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1038]: libinput error: event15 - ELAN0718:01 04F3:30FD Touchpad: kernel bug: Touch jump detected and discarded.
Mar 27 21:13:05 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1038]: See https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.10.4/touchpad_jumping_cursor.html for details
Mar 29 02:05:03 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1650]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce: offset negative (-11ms)
Mar 29 02:05:24 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1650]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce: offset negative (-65ms)
Mar 29 02:05:26 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1650]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce: offset negative (-60ms)
Mar 29 02:05:26 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1650]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce short: offset negative (-73ms)
Mar 29 02:05:27 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1650]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce short: offset negative (-9ms)
Mar 29 02:05:33 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1650]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce: offset negative (-1ms)
Mar 29 02:05:33 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1650]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce short: offset negative (-14ms)
Mar 29 02:18:53 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1650]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce: offset negative (-8ms)
Mar 29 02:18:53 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1650]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce short: offset negative (-21ms)
Mar 29 02:31:55 dogus sudo[4240]:    dogus : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/dogus ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/libinput list-devices
Mar 29 03:02:49 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1650]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce short: offset negative (-1ms)
Mar 29 19:26:42 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1679]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce: offset negative (-8ms)
Mar 29 19:26:42 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1679]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-22ms)
Mar 29 19:28:54 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1679]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-1ms)
Mar 29 20:34:06 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1585]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-2749ms)
Mar 29 20:34:06 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1585]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-1486ms)
Mar 29 20:34:06 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1585]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-858ms)
Mar 29 20:34:06 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1585]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-179ms)
Mar 29 20:34:06 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1585]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-176ms)
Mar 29 22:21:16 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1585]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-1618ms)
Mar 29 23:37:14 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1585]: libinput error: client bug: timer event10 keyboard: offset negative (-2624ms)
Mar 30 00:33:04 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1585]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce short: offset negative (-0ms)
Mar 30 00:52:11 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1677]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce: offset negative (-137ms)
Mar 30 00:52:11 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1677]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce short: offset negative (-150ms)
Mar 30 01:25:22 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1052]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce: offset negative (-13ms)
Mar 30 01:25:22 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1052]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce short: offset negative (-26ms)
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1'
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1'
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control'
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) libinput: Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control: needs a virtual subdevice
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 System Control'
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Mar 30 01:30:59 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1'
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru'
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) HP Wireless hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HP Wireless hotkeys'
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) HP WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HP WMI hotkeys'
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control'
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:00 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) libinput: Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control: is a virtual subdevice
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:31:06 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1219]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 01:32:18 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1662]: libinput error: client bug: timer event17 tap: offset negative (-822ms)
Mar 30 01:32:18 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1662]: libinput error: client bug: timer event17 tap: offset negative (-773ms)
Mar 30 01:37:18 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1662]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-9ms)
Mar 30 22:57:12 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1047]: libinput error: client bug: timer event12 keyboard: offset negative (-627ms)
Mar 30 22:57:12 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1047]: libinput error: client bug: timer event6 keyboard: offset negative (-627ms)
Mar 30 23:08:52 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce: offset negative (-164ms)
Mar 30 23:08:52 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce: offset negative (-59ms)
Mar 30 23:08:52 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce short: offset negative (-72ms)
Mar 30 23:17:01 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1628]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce: offset negative (-17ms)
Mar 30 23:17:01 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1628]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce short: offset negative (-12ms)
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) libinput: Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control: needs a virtual subdevice
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 System Control'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) HP Wireless hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HP Wireless hotkeys'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) HP WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HP WMI hotkeys'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control'
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:30 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) libinput: Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control: is a virtual subdevice
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:22:41 dogus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3091]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 30 23:35:00 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1646]: libinput error: client bug: timer event17 tap: offset negative (-762ms)
Mar 30 23:35:09 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1646]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce: offset negative (-5ms)
Mar 30 23:35:09 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1646]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-18ms)
Mar 31 00:23:10 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1646]: libinput error: client bug: timer event12 keyboard: offset negative (-1635ms)
Mar 31 00:23:10 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1646]: libinput error: client bug: timer event17 keyboard: offset negative (-1635ms)
Mar 31 00:39:06 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1133]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-3ms)
Mar 31 00:40:50 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1637]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce: offset negative (-11ms)
Mar 31 00:45:17 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1637]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-10ms)
Mar 31 00:46:11 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1637]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-1ms)
Mar 31 01:08:57 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1663]: libinput error: client bug: timer event12 keyboard: offset negative (-2985ms)
Mar 31 01:08:57 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1663]: libinput error: client bug: timer event17 keyboard: offset negative (-2985ms)
Mar 31 01:08:57 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1663]: libinput error: client bug: timer event12 keyboard: offset negative (-1637ms)
Mar 31 01:08:57 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1663]: libinput error: client bug: timer event17 keyboard: offset negative (-1637ms)
Mar 31 01:17:52 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1663]: libinput error: client bug: timer event12 keyboard: offset negative (-1939ms)
Mar 31 01:17:52 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1663]: libinput error: client bug: timer event17 keyboard: offset negative (-1939ms)
Mar 31 12:41:09 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1665]: libinput error: client bug: timer event15 tap: offset negative (-837ms)
Mar 31 12:41:09 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1665]: libinput error: client bug: timer event15 tap: offset negative (-700ms)
Mar 31 12:41:09 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1665]: libinput error: client bug: timer event15 tap: offset negative (-602ms)
Mar 31 12:41:09 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1665]: libinput error: client bug: timer event15 tap: offset negative (-284ms)
Mar 31 12:41:10 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1665]: libinput error: client bug: timer event15 tap: offset negative (-131ms)
Mar 31 12:41:17 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1665]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce: offset negative (-33ms)
Mar 31 12:41:17 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1665]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce: offset negative (-37ms)
Mar 31 12:41:17 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1665]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-50ms)
Mar 31 12:41:23 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1665]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-10ms)
Mar 31 15:11:00 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1036]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce: offset negative (-0ms)
Mar 31 15:11:00 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1036]: libinput error: client bug: timer event9 debounce short: offset negative (-13ms)
Mar 31 15:11:52 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1647]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce: offset negative (-286ms)
Mar 31 15:11:52 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1647]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-299ms)
Mar 31 15:22:41 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1654]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-4ms)
Mar 31 15:23:32 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1654]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce: offset negative (-27ms)
Mar 31 15:23:32 dogus org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1654]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-40ms)
```

Comment: As Peter told you, you need to re-configure touchpad with Gnome settings to have right-click. If touchpad works for you now, please [close the report](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/463). Btw, I'm not sure why are you editing `/etc/default/grub` *(the newest installed kernel should be the default)*, but note that your edits will not have effect until the new `/boot/grub.cfg` is created from this file *(IIRC update-grub command on Ubuntu)*. Make sure you know what you're doing as edits to grub files may easily leave your system unbootable.

Comment: "the newest installed kernel should be the default"
Yes but the touchpad doesn't work properly on earlier kernel (5.3.0-43), Didn't work in fedora 32 beta either.

Comment: Okay, I will try Peter's advice, If that solves the issue, I will close the report.Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I booted into Fedora and the touchpad works. How is this possible? The changes I did in Ubuntu caused to change in BIOS somehow and thats the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the second answer. I made an important discovery that I had to share.

I discovered that the issue might not be related to the kernel as well. Because I selected 'F11 System Recovery' option during a boot, while I was desperate.

When I press F11, it just regularly boots into Ubuntu without any 'visual' thing happening. But everytime I select System Recovery option, the touchpad works in every time.

I tried this out by 10 times booting normally, and by 10 times selecting 'System Recovery' option during boot.
The touchpad didn't work during 10 normal boot trial, and It worked every single time when I selected 'System Recovery' option during boot.

Why that might be?